# Vimscript: outputting into a new (split) window

Tags: vim

From within Vimscript, how does one open a new split window and insert the contents of a variable?

I'm trying to write a script that applies a function to the current buffer and displays the result in a split window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open a new window, use `:split`. To insert the contents of a variable, use `:call append(0, g:some_var)`

Answer (score 0):

I never used vimscript (excluding simple keyboard mappings and settings), but here are some links that might help:

Here's how to make a new split window (take a look at the source):

- http://www.vtk.org/Bug/view.php?id=11310

Here's how you insert characters:

- http://captsolo.net/info/blog_b.php/2004/07/31/a_vim_script_to_insert_the_current_line_

Btw, here's a very nice IBM tutorial that might be useful:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-5/index.html

Comment: vtk.org has erased bug 11310. captsolo is gone but can be found here: http://web.archive.org/web/20120701100728/http://captsolo.net/info/blog_b.php/2004/07/31/a_vim_script_to_insert_the_current_line_

Comment: and now the ibm link is dead too. This answer should probably be removed as it provides no value anymore.